# Evaluating a variable while calling System in Ruby

Tags: ruby, system-calls, ruby-1.9.3

I want to actually call the following in `Ruby`

```
echo "<html><body><b>BOLD</b></body></html>" | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "HTML content"  -- anushka.misra2@gmail.com
```

I was successfully able to do it in Ruby with `system()` method:

```
system 'echo "<html><body><b>BOLD</b></body></html>" | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "HTML content"  -- anushka.misra2@gmail.com'
```

Now, I want email to be a variable:

```
email = anushka.misra2@gmail.com
system 'echo "<html><body><b>BOLD</b></body></html>" | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "HTML content"  -- $email'
```

But this fails as it doesn't evaluate email variable. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
system %Q{echo "<html><body><b>BOLD</b></body></html>" | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "HTML content"  -- #{email}}
```

`#{foo}` is the Ruby way to add a value into a string. `#{foo}` is only evaluated in strings with `"` (not `'`). Where `%Q{}` does the same, but you do not have to escape `"` inside the string.